# Facebook request integration on Android

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, request

I need to implement Facebook Requests logic to my app. It should work this way:
1. user sends request to his friends via Facebook dialog
2. when any of them tap the notification inside Facebook app Notifications tab it navigates him to the app with Intent containing any parameters. If the app isnt installed - the Play Market page of the app is opened.

I have already implemented the code, but still when I tap on the notification - nothing happens.
I am pretty sure the problem is with app's settings in Facebook so-called App Dashboard. But the documentation is very hard to understand, at some places there are out-of-date screenshots and names...
Help please to set up the app.